# Use DISTINCT with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by, distinct

I want to Alter my following stored procedure

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spEGCRedemptionReportForMHR]  

@DateTo datetime,
@DateFrom datetime,
@MerchantID varchar(11),
@Pan varchar(16)
As
Set @DateTo = @DateTo +1
Select Distinct
Convert(varchar(50),pt.TransactionDate,103) 'TransactionDate',
m.MerchantName1 MerchantName,
m.MerchantAddress Location,
m.MerchantID,
pt.TerminalID,
pt.batchnumber 'Batch #',
pt.SequenceNumber 'Receipt #',
pt.PAN 'Card Number',
c.EmbossName 'Card Holder Name',

Convert(Decimal(10,2),Case when pt.TransactionTypeID=2 then (pt.TotalAmount) end) As 'Points Redeemed',
Convert(Decimal(10,2),Case when pt.TransactionTypeID=2 then (((pt.TotalAmount)/(cc.usdconversionrate))/2) end) as 'Total Payment Amount (AED)', --/cc.USDConversionRate end) As 'Total Amount in AED',
Convert(Decimal(10,2),Case when pt.TransactionTypeID=2 then (((pt.TotalAmount)/(cc.usdconversionrate))/2) -15 end) as 'Total loaded Amount (AED)',
3.00 as 'Procco Share',
Convert(Decimal(10,2),Case when pt.TransactionTypeID=2 then (((pt.TotalAmount)/(cc.usdconversionrate))/2) - 3 end) as 'Settlement Amount'

from POS_Transactions pt
inner join Terminal t on t.TerminalID=pt.TerminalID
inner join Merchant m on m.MerchantID=t.MerchantID
inner join Card c on c.EmbossLine=pt.PAN
inner join Share s on s.MerchantID=m.MerchantID,Currency cc
where IsEmaar =1 and
cc.CurrencyCode='AED'
--and m.isemaarmerchant = 1
and (m.MerchantID=@MerchantID or @MerchantID='-999')
and (pt.TransactionDate>=@datefrom and pt.TransactionDate<=@dateto)
and (pt.PAN=@Pan or @Pan ='-999')
order by pt.TransactionDate
```

But it throws an error everytime I am trying to execute it

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

I have already used `pt.TransactionDate` in my select but still its asking me to include it since it is in my order by clause. What is possibly wrong with my query?

Comment: you should either `order by Convert(varchar(50),pt.TransactionDate,103)` or use `pt.TransactionDate` directly in your select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ORDER BY 'TransactionDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not that helpful, but the comment by [ughai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4436237/ughai) is correct. The engine is particular about how the column is modified in the SELECT statement, and the exact form must be included in the "ORDER BY."

I have run into this when concatenating columns for output reasons, and it gets ugly fast.

You must

```
ORDER BY Convert(varchar(50),pt.TransactionDate,103)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates then you can include grouped fields whether they're in the select list of not. The downside is you'll have to list *all* the columns used but this will do it.

```
GROUP BY 
pt.TransactionDate,
m.MerchantName1,
m.MerchantAddress ,
m.MerchantID,
pt.TerminalID,
pt.batchnumber,
pt.SequenceNumber,
pt.PAN ,
c.EmbossName,
pt.TransactionTypeID,
pt.TotalAmount,
cc.usdconversionrate
ORDER BY pt.TransactionDate
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes the column pt.TransactionDate appears in the SELECT but, in inside the CONVERT function as below:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), pt.TransactionDate, 103) 'TransactionDate',
```

add pt.TransactionDate by itself as an extra column as follows:

```
  ...     
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), pt.TransactionDate, 103) 'TransactionDate',
    pt.TransactionDate, -- <-- here
    m.MerchantName1 MerchantName,
    m.MerchantAddress Location,
    m.MerchantID,
    pt.TerminalID,
  ....
```

Comment: Why would I want to show the same field twice? isnt there any other alternative?

Comment: Why not. It shouldn't be a big deal. If you really don't want it in the select list then you must sort by CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), pt.TransactionDate, 103) as suggested above. But be aware that it may not sort the way you want.